# Ubuntu LUKS won't accept password after installing Nvidia GPU driver

Tags: ubuntu, drivers, encryption, gpu, luks

I have Ubuntu 18.04.3 running with full disk encryption on my 2014 macbook pro 15. To take advantage of the Nvidia GPU on my computer I decided to install the proprietary Nvidia driver (390) which was tagged as "tested" in the Additional Drivers window. In order to complete the installation I had to restart the computer, but now I cannot log in because LUKS will no longer accept my password as the correct one.

I suppose the keyboard still works as intended because when I interrupt the boot sequence with ESC and type in the grub prompt the keyboard outputs the alphabet and symbols as expected. I have also tried the advice of pressing Caps+Shift+Alt to "reset" the keyboard without success.

Any advice or links that may be useful would be much appreciated.

Edit: Furthermore, I cannot access the encrypted drive through a live usb, it is as if the Nvidia 390 driver changed the password to my LUKS encrypted disk. Is my only option to do a fresh install?

Borrowed picture, but this is the prompt I can't get passed:

[image: Borrowed picture, but same window]

Comment: Are you using Plymouth or other graphical boot screen (I think Ubuntu comes with it built in)?

Comment: I don't understand what's weird about that "weird thing".

Comment: I use the standard built in graphical boot screen that comes with Ubuntu 18

Comment: @gronostaj  Sorry, I was being a bit unclear and have made an edit. It was weird to me to see the expected symbols being output in the grub prompt because I  assumed the keyboard layout must have changed

Comment: Also I cannot access the encrypted drive through a live usb, it is as if the Nvidia 390 driver changed the password to my LUKS encrypted disk